# AFNetworking 2.0 parsed data not displaying in table view

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, afnetworking-2

my issue: no data is displaying in the table.

below is the code being used to retrieve the json object array and parse it using AFNetworking 2.0. I have a UIViewController where I placed a tableview with a prototype cell that has a reuse identifier EventCell. All I want is to display a title and an image in every cell.  I get no errors at runtime.

NSDictionary+events.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (events)

- (NSString *)eventImage;
- (NSString *)eventTitle;
- (NSDate *)eventDate;
- (NSNumber *)eventPrice;
- (NSNumber *)eventTicketsTotal;
@end
```

NSDictionary+events.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+events.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (events)



- (NSString *)eventImage
{
    return self[@"event_image"];

}

- (NSString *)eventTitle
{
    return self[@"event_title"];

}

- (NSDate *)eventDate
{
    //    NSString *dateStr = self[@"date"]; // date = "2013-01-15";
    return [NSDate date];
}

- (NSNumber *)eventPrice
{
    NSString *cc = self[@"event_price"];
    NSNumber *n = @([cc intValue]);
    return n;
}

- (NSNumber *)eventTicketsTotal{
    NSString *cc = self[@"event_tickets_total"];
    NSNumber *n = @([cc intValue]);
    return n;
}

@end
```

NSDictionary+events_package.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (NSDictionary_events_package)

-(NSArray *)upcomingWeather;
@end
```

NSDictionary+events_package.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+events_package.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionary_events_package)


- (NSArray *)upcomingWeather
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    return dict[@"events"];
}
@end
```

TDViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NSDictionary+events.h"

@interface TDViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

TDViewController.m

```
#import "TDViewController.h"

#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "TDSecondViewController.h"
#import "NSDictionary+events_package.h"

static NSString * const BaseURLString = @"http://xx.zzz.yy.xx/test/";

@interface TDViewController ()

@property(strong) NSDictionary *events;

@end

@implementation TDViewController   

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // 1
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@event_json.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSLog(@"web service address: %@", string);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // 3
        self.events = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Events"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // 5
    [operation start];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WeatherDetailSegue"]){
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        TDSecondViewController *wac = (TDSecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSDictionary *w;
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            {
                w = [self.events upcomingWeather][indexPath.row];
                //NSLog( @"this is w: %@", w );
            }
            wac.weatherDictionary = w;

        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(!self.events)
        return 0;

    NSArray *upcomingWeather = [self.events upcomingWeather];
    return [upcomingWeather count];
    NSLog( @"the count is %lu", (long)[upcomingWeather count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *daysWeather = nil;


    NSArray *upcomingWeather = [self.events upcomingWeather];
    daysWeather = upcomingWeather[indexPath.row];
    NSLog( @"this is daysWeather: %@", daysWeather );
    cell.textLabel.text = [daysWeather eventTitle];
     NSLog(@"The content of arry is%@",daysWeather);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:daysWeather.eventImage];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];

    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                          placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                       weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                                       [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                                   } failure:nil];    
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
}

@end
```

below is the nslog output I get when i run the project on the simulator (note not all of the nslog statements are displaying).

```
2014-04-06 21:47:04.592 iCLUB[9198:60b] webservice address:     
http://xx.zzz.yy.xx/test/event_json.php?format=json
2014-04-06 21:47:04.685 iCLUB[9198:60b] {
data =     {
    events =         (
                    {
            "event_date" = "7-5-2014";
            "event_id" = 22;
            "event_image" = "http://xx.zzz.yy.xx/...";
            "event_price" = 150;
            "event_tickets_total" = 200;
            "event_title" = "New Event Title";
        },
                    {
            "event_date" = "3-2-2014";
            "event_id" = 23;
            "event_image" = "http://xx.zzz.yy.xx/...";
            "event_price" = 150;
            "event_tickets_total" = 200;
            "event_title" = "New Event Title 2";
        },
                    {
            "event_date" = "9-25-2014";
            "event_id" = 24;
            "event_image" = "http://xx.zzz.yy.xx/...";
            "event_price" = 150;
            "event_tickets_total" = 200;
            "event_title" = "New Event Title 33";
        }
    );
};
}
```

I just can't catch what the issue is, the app builds and runs on the simulator, but the cells appear completely empty.  I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks, JT.

Comment: you should proper model classes instead of categories on NSDictionary.

Comment: Possible problems include either (a) you have not hooked up the `IBOutlet` for the table view (which would prevent `reloadData` from doing anything); or (b) you have not set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view to be the view controller (in which case, any call to `reloadData` would result in no calls to your `UITableViewDataSource` methods). I'd suggest checking that `self.tableView` and `self.tableView.dataSource` are non-`nil`.

Comment: AFNetworking offere nothing more then NSURLSession.

Comment: @Joride That's not entirely true. `AFHTTPSessionManager` offers the request and response serialization functionality and the simplified `GET`, `POST`, etc. methods that make it much easier to construct complicated requests. Admittedly, AFNetworking doesn't currently offer the `NSOperation`-based patterns for `NSURLSession`, but Mattt reports that he's working on that.

Answer (score 1):

Possible sources of the problem include:

- Failure to connect the `IBOutlet` for the table view. If the `tableView` property is not hooked up properly, it would be `nil`, and thus `[self.tableView reloadData]` would do nothing (because sending a message to a `nil` object does nothing).

  Frankly, I'm unclear how this `tableView` property is getting set, because it lacks the typical `IBOutlet` qualification used when connecting controls in Interface Builder and I don't see you setting it programmatically, either.
- Failure to specify your view controller as the `delegate` and, more importantly, the `dataSource` of the table view. If this is the case, even if you successfully called `[self.tableView reloadData]`, it would not result in the `UITableViewDataSource` methods being called).

I'd suggest checking that `self.tableView` and `self.tableView.dataSource` are non-`nil`.

Answer (score 0):

1. This NSLog statement in numberOfRowsInSection won't ever be called because the method returns before the statement!

   ```
       return [upcomingWeather count];
       NSLog( @"the count is %lu", (long)[upcomingWeather count]);
   ```
2. It seems like cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called, which can be due to various reasons including the UITableView datasource and delegate not being set, numberOfRowsInSection returning 0, or your TableView being nil. Using the debugger will allow you to see which of these scenarios is happening.

   Check out Apple's [resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html) on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse json data , use above code

```
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    self.events = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Comment: Hi, when I change my code with what you have above I still get a blank set of cells. When I do NSLog(@"self.eventst: %@", self.events); it displays output that I originally got for NSLog(@"%@", responseObject); that is displayed above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set the delegate and dataSource for self.tableView? It's not done for you automatically when you don't subclass UITableViewController.

<del>I believe the JSON you're getting from the API is invalid. The Array of `events` should be enclosed in brackets `[]` not parentheses. Additionally, JSON doesn't use semicolons. See the JSON [spec](http://www.json.org/).</del>

Comment: No semicolons in my code.  JSON is correct as far as I know. What I displayed above is the output of NSLog(@"%@", responseObject); after the JSON is consumed.

Comment: I set the delegate and datasource this way:self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;...No change.

Comment: @user3007683 And is `self.tableView`, itself, not `nil`?

Comment: Are the other NSLog statements executing? If not, there's still something wrong with TableView not calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Perhaps you haven't inited self.tableView itself (either from Storyboard/NIB via IBOutlet or `[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:]`